# COLMAP running error in remote server while running Non-Rigid NeRF

Tags: deep-learning, graphics, computer-vision, qt5, structure-from-motion

I was checking the github code of LLFF : https://github.com/Fyusion/LLFF, Non-Rigid NeRF : https://github.com/facebookresearch/nonrigid_nerf and followed the suggested steps to install requirements. While running a preprocess file which return poses from images by SfM using COLMAP. I was getting the following error while executing the preprocessing in a remote server. Can anyone please help me with solving this?

**python preprocess.py --input data/example_sequence1/**

```
Need to run COLMAP
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl, xcb.

*** Aborted at 1660905461 (unix time) try "date -d @1660905461" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGABRT (@0x3e900138a9f) received by PID 1280671 (TID 0x7f5740d49000) from PID 1280671; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f57463a2197 google::(anonymous namespace)::FailureSignalHandler()
    @     0x7f574421f420 (unknown)
    @     0x7f5743bf300b gsignal
    @     0x7f5743bd2859 abort
    @     0x7f57442be35b QMessageLogger::fatal()
    @     0x7f574477c799 QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration()
    @     0x7f574477cb6f QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher()
    @     0x7f57443dbb62 QCoreApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x7f574477d1e1 QGuiApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x7f5744c03bc5 QApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x562bbb634975 colmap::RunFeatureExtractor()
    @     0x562bbb61d1a0 main
    @     0x7f5743bd4083 __libc_start_main
    @     0x562bbb620e39 (unknown)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imgs2poses.py", line 18, in <module>
    gen_poses(args.scenedir, args.match_type)
  File "/data1/user_data/ashish/NeRF/LLFF/llff/poses/pose_utils.py", line 268, in gen_poses
    run_colmap(basedir, match_type)
  File "/data1/user_data/ashish/NeRF/LLFF/llff/poses/colmap_wrapper.py", line 35, in run_colmap
    feat_output = ( subprocess.check_output(feature_extractor_args, universal_newlines=True) )
  File "/home/ashish/anaconda3/envs/nrnerf/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/home/ashish/anaconda3/envs/nrnerf/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['colmap', 'feature_extractor', '--database_path', 'scenedir/database.db', '--image_path', 'scenedir/images', '--ImageReader.single_camera', '1']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
```

'''

Comment: direct your bug reports/usage help to the authors of those repositories.